# transmission over isomorphism finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, group-isomorphism

Considering three isomorphism finite fields of size 256 A, B and C; where A and B are $GF(2^8)/GF(2)$ constructed with two distinct irreducible polynomials of degree 8, and C is a tower field $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$.

Having tow matrices M1 and M2, where M1 (respectively M2) maps the members of A (respectively B) to their corresponding member of B (respectively C); does $M3=M2*M1$ maps the members of A to their corresponding member of C?

Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Up to isomorphism, there is only one field of size $256$. But it does allow non-trivial automorphisms, so what do you mean with "corresponding member"? Also, with respect to which bases do your matrices describe the isomorphisms?

Comment: Please refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399922/finding-matrix-for-mapping-members-of-isomorphism-finite-fields for more declaration.

Comment: If $T_1$ is a homomorphism (necessarily injective) from $GF(4)$ to $GF(16)$, and $T_2$ is a homomorphism from $GF(16)$ to $GF(256)$, then, yes $T_2\circ T_1$ is a homomorphism from $GF(4)$ to $GF(256)$. And as long as you use the same basis of $GF(16)$ (over $GF(4)$ or over $GF(2)$) when presenting these homomorphism (that are also linear transformations), yes, the composition becomes the matrix product.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are striving to do here. Just in case it helps you, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/166932/11619) I describe a simple recursive way of constructing the tower $$GF(2)\subset GF(4)\subset GF(16)\subset GF(256)\subset GF(65536)\subset \cdots.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks for your answer. Actually, I want to compute $x^-1$ in $GF(2^8)$ constructed with a specific primitive polynomial and implement this computation in hardware. A common method to deal with the considerable area requirement of inversion computation in $GF(2^8)$ is mapping the members of $GF(2^8)$ to a tower field such as $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$ or $GF((2^4)^2)$. We map the members into the tower field with a matrix(M2 in the above question) multiplication, compute the inversion, and then coming back to the first $GF(2^8)$ by matrix ($M2^-1$) multiplication.

Comment: Now, I need to know if I have matrices M1 and M2; M2 for mapping the members of $GF(2^8)$ (B in the question) with an specific irreducible polynomial into the tower field (C in the question) and M1 for mapping the members of $GF(2^8)$ (A in the question) with another specific irreducible polynomial into B; can I map the members of A to the tower field C by multiplication in $M2*M1$?

Comment: Ok, so $M_1$ and $M_2$ describe mappings from $GF((2^4)^2)$ to $GF(2^8)$ and from $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$ to $GF((2^4)^2)$. Not entirely unlike [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/167468/11619)? As you see from my attempt there, I'm not well versed in this problem area.
Anyway, matrix multiplication corresponds to composition of linear transformations, and inverse matrix give the inverse transformation.